# JSF Bean doens´t run code after specific method call

Tags: jsf, backing-beans

i have a `commandButton`, which calls a method inside the backing bean. This bean is *ViewScoped* and calls a service method, which is *ApplicationScoped*(inside there it calls repository method which saves the data from the form inside a database). 
Now the service and repository methods run normal, but the code after those calls isnt run(e.g. the log and the redirect).

Here is the backing bean:

```java
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class SubmitController implements Serializable {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SubmitController.class);

    private String userName;
    private String title;
    private String url;
    private String text;

    @Inject
    PostService postService;

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        LOG.info("Initialize SubmitController");
    }

    public void submitPost() throws IOException {
        long postID = this.postService.submitPost(this.userName, this.title, this.url, this.text);

        LOG.info("postID: {}", postID);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext()
                .redirect("item.xhtml");
    }
}
```

The service:

```java
@Service
public class PostService {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostService.class);

    @Inject
    PostRepository postRepository;

    public long submitPost(final String userName, final String title, final String url, final String text) throws IOException {
        Post post = Post.newPost()
                .withUser(new User(userName))
                .withTitle(new Title(title))
                .withUrl(new Url(url))
                .withText(new Text(text))
                .build();

        LOG.info("Submit post: {}", post.toString());

        this.postRepository.submitPost(post);

        Post refrence = this.postRepository.getRefrence(post);

        LOG.info("Refrence: {}", refrence.toString());

        return refrence.getId();
    }
}
```

and the repository:

```java
@Repository
public class PostRepository {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostRepository.class);

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "default")
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public Post getRefrence(final Post post) {
        return this.entityManager.getReference(Post.class, post);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void submitPost(final Post post) {
        LOG.info("Save post");

        this.entityManager.persist(post);
    }
}
```

Note that the Repository and Service annotation are *ApplicationScoped*.

Has it something to do with the scopes or why isn´t the code after `long postID = this.postService.submitPost(this.userName, this.title, this.url, this.text);` run?

Comment: Didn't it just threw an exception?

Comment: no, there were no exceptions thrown

Comment: The symptoms described so far confirm this. If you didn't see it, then you didn't look good, or it was swallowed. Just run a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't add the `@Transactional` annotation to the repository method. That fixed my poblem